# Dockerized PostgreSQL: psql: FATAL: the database system is starting up

Tags: postgresql, docker, ansible, docker-compose, ansible-container

I am trying to build and run two Docker containers hosting PostgreSQL and Citus extension using `ansible-container`. I am aware that Citus provides containers, but I want to build my own.

My `container.yaml` looks as follows:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:

  database_master:
    image: hackermd/ubuntu-trusty-python
    user: postgres
    expose:
      - 5043
    entrypoint: ['dumb-init', '--']
    command: ['/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster', '9.6', 'master', 'start']
    links:
      - database_worker
    depends_on:
      - database_worker

  database_worker:
    image: hackermd/ubuntu-trusty-python
    user: postgres
    expose:
    - 9700
  entrypoint: ['dumb-init', '--']
  command: ['/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster', '9.6', 'worker', 'start']
```

During the build process I can start and stop the cluster via `pg_ctlcluster` and it finishes successfully. However, when I subsequently run the containers, I get the following error:

```
$ docker logs ansible_database_master_1
Removed stale pid file.
Warning: connection to the database failed, disabling startup checks:
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

When I build containers with `command: []` and run `ps aux` inside the container, I see the following process:

```
postgres    14  1.6  0.1 307504  3480 ?        Ds   16:46   0:00 postgres: 9.6/master: startup process
```

I've also tried without the `dumb-init` entrypoint. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is related to the default shutdown method of the `pg_ctl stop` mode (`pg_ctl` gets called by `pg_ctlcluster`). Stopping the cluster via `pg_ctlcluster` with the `pg_ctl` option `-m smart` during the build process solves this problem:

```
pg_ctlcluster 9.6 master stop -- -m smart
```

The "smart" method waits for active clients to disconnect and online backups to finish before shutting down in contrast to the default "fast" method. This is explained in the documentation of [pg_ctl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html).

In addition, the container would exit once the `pg_ctlcontrol` process successfully started the database cluster via `postgres` (`pg_ctlcontrol` -> `pg_ctl` -> `postgres`). To prevent this, `postgres` can be called directly. The `container.yml` file would then look as follows:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:

  database_master:
    image: hackermd/ubuntu-trusty-python
    user: postgres
    expose:
      - 5043
    command: ['dumb-init', '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/postgres', '-D', '/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/master']
    links:
      - database_worker
    depends_on:
      - database_worker

  database_worker:
    image: hackermd/ubuntu-trusty-python
    user: postgres
    expose:
      - 9700
    command: ['dumb-init', '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/postgres', '-D', '/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/worker']
```

Comment: Had the same error under vaguely the same situation. Using pg_ctlcluster to shut down the service neatly between RUNs in my Dockerfile solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: What if pg not a cluster and just one standalone db??

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with starting postgres using pg_ctl and right after running tests in my docker container. What fixed it was adding "smart mode" to my command, i.e:

```
su - postgres -c 'pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l /var/lib/postgresql/log.log -m smart'
```

Comment: And smart mode means this: `Smart” mode disallows new connections, then waits for all existing clients to disconnect`, from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html